# How to log specific value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sublimetext3, key-value

I have a big multidimensional array and need a quick way to verify the **amount of occurrence** of certain values in that array (how many times the value appears in the array).
The values I need to check are placed within another array.

The array looks like this with 20.000 objects in it.

```
var array = [
    {key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: False", 
    "Green: True"]}, 
    {key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green: 
    True"]}
];
```

I tried this in my loop:

```
console.log(array[i].attributes === "Garden: False");
```

However it doesn't work.
Would it be easier to check it in sublime text with the "find all" tool? I already did that but was unsure if sublime finds all the `"Garden: False"` im searching after … Thats why I wanted to log it.

Comment: use indexOf : `console.log(array[i].attributes.indexOF("Garden: False") > -1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the values of the attributes array.

```js
var array = [{ key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: False", "Green: True"] }, { key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green: True"] }];

array.forEach(function(a) {
    console.log(a.attributes.some(function(b) {
        return b === 'Garden: False';
    }));
});
```

For just counting, you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array = [{ key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: False", "Green: True"] }, { key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green: True"] }],
    count = array.reduce(function(r, a) {
        return r + a.attributes.some(function(b) {
            return b === 'Garden: False';
        });
    }, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Comment: i had to same issue , your solution work for me thx for answering the question

Comment: @Nina Scholz Hi Nina! I wasn't specific enough and edited my post … I basically need to count how many times this value is in the array. How could I dot that?

Comment: @UnknownUser : use filter and get length of result array

Comment: @PranavCBalan Could you write an example how to do that?

Comment: @UnknownUser, does attributes could contain more than one matching string? do you liek to kount the occurences of the string, or just how many items have attributes with matching strings?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, attributes contains just one matching string per object. I just want to know how many "Garden : False" are in the complete array. The outer array containing all objects.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are checking if an array is equal to an item in the array.

To find if that item is in the array you can do the following:

```
console.log(array[i].attributes.indexOf("Garden: False") >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Among many ways of doing this job one is using `.filter()`

```js
var arr    = [{key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: False", "Green: True"]}, {key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green: True"]}],
    result = arr.filter(o => o.attributes.includes("Garden: False"));
console.log(result)
```

If you need the count then check `result.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use every for something short and quick.

```js
var array = [{key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: False", "Green: True"]},{key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green:True"]},{key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green:True"]},{key1: "value", key2: "value", attributes: ["Garden: True", "Green:True"]}],count = 0;

      array.every((x) => x.attributes[0] === 'Garden: True' ? [count++] : true);

      console.log(count);
```